# Formatting an Excel file for correct date format

Tags: c#, excel, list, date

I have `list` which is generated by the data from an `excel` file. In the excel I have a Date Column with following rows

```
03/15/2014  
02/15/2014   
01/15/2014   
12/14/2014   
11/14/2014
```

The above date is supposed to be like `MM/dd/yyyy` but for some reasons, the application that is generating the excel file just processes the data as text and and instead of generating an yeah in yyyy format it just keeps year in the Day filed and generates a random year.

So, in the above example data `03,02,01,12,11` are months which is what I want but `15,15,15,14,14` should be years instead it is generated as Day in the above example.

The actual data should be

```
03/dd/2015  
02/dd/2015   
01/dd/2015   
12/dd/2014   
11/dd/2014
```

Now, is there any method in `C#` through which I can process this list of Dates and get another list with correct Date?

Provided that `dd` can be any date but should be same for all

Comment: lower case `mm` is for minutes, For month it is upper case `MM`

Comment: Would it be easier just to use excel --> format --> general --> date --> type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this as my answer

```
foreach(var item in SourceList)
    {
        int newYear = Convert.ToInt32(item.Year.ToString().Substring(0,2) + item.Day.ToString());
        DateTime result = new DateTime(newYear, item.Month, 10);
        ResultList.Add(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add an extra column in excel to convert the value:

```
=DATE(DAY(A1)+2000,MONTH(A1),1)
```

If you have the 'wrong' date in `c#` `dt1` variable:

```
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt1.Day+2000,dt1.Month,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to convert the string into DateTime.

Then you can extract the day, month and year using the corresponding [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties(v=VS.100).aspx).
Credit goes to Amsakanna

Comment: Well, Thanks but my list or excel are already in DateTime format but just incorrectly considered year has date

Comment: Ah, okay.  I understand now, I'll try and do another thing.

Comment: Sure, but please keep in mind that I can have anything in Day field but should be equal throughout the list